# Handling Drag and Drop on a view

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I am currently trying to use the drag and drop events to be able to ensure that a particular view can be dragged and dropped anywhere on the screen. So I consulted the code at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_drag_and_drop.htm

But what is happening is that the drag works perfectly, but when the drop event is triggered the view does not get placed over the layout or for that matter anywhere on the window.
While i would specifically want it to be visible anywhere on the screen, the idea is to drag the imageview on top of the layout with id = "@+id/Layout" 
My code is

activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/canvas"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#0099cc"
tools:context="com.example.user.gesturedemo.Activity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/Layout"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/anImageView"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/signboard"
        android:contentDescription="Image" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/aImageView"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/letter"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:contentDescription="Image"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<com.example.user.gesturedemo.ObjectImageView
    android:id="@+id/objectImageView"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/a"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:contentDescription="Image"/>
```

Activity class has

```
public class AnActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String msg = AnActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private com.example.user.gesturedemo.ObjectImageView alObject;
private RelativeLayout canvas;
private android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_blackboard);
    canvas = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.canvas);
    alObject = (com.example.user.gesturedemo.ObjectImageView) findViewById(R.id.alphabetObjectImageView);

    alObject.setOnLongClickListener(mObjectLongClickListener);

    alObject.setOnDragListener(mObjectOnDragListener);

    alObject.setOnTouchListener(mObjectObjectTouchListener);

   // canvas.setOnDragListener(mObjectOnDragListener);

}


private View.OnLongClickListener mObjectLongClickListener = new     View.OnLongClickListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence)v.getTag());
        String[] mimeTypes = {ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN};

        ClipData dragData = new ClipData(v.getTag().toString(),mimeTypes, item);
        View.DragShadowBuilder myShadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(alObject);

        v.startDrag(dragData,myShadow,null,0);
        return true;
    }
};



private View.OnDragListener mObjectOnDragListener = new View.OnDragListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction())
        {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                layoutParams =(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams();
                Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED");

                // Do nothing
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED");
                int x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                int y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED :
                Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED");
                x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord;
                layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord;
                v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION  :
                Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION");
                x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED   :
                Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED");

                // Do nothing
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                Log.d(msg, "ACTION_DROP event");
                Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED");

                x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord;
                layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord;
                v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            default: break;
        }
        return true;
    }
};

private View.OnTouchListener mObjectObjectTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(alphabetObject);

            alObject.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, alObject, 0);
            alObject.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

}

Comment: does it work ok if you dont use the extra relative layout?

Comment: let me try that, but that extra layout is important It compartmentalizes the immovable portion of the UI.

Comment: Nope it does not work even after removing the Relative layout.

Comment: One thing to note is that logcat shows this message I/ViewRootImpl: Reporting drop result: false

Comment: not sure what might the problem in your case but have a look here at another similar tutorial -- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html

Comment: Where is the initialize of `alObject` in `onCreate`? and who is `alphabetObject`? and why you using both `OnTouchListener` and `OnLongClickListener`?

Comment: al, alObject and alphabetObject are the same variables thanks modifying the same in the original question.